# C# unsafe: AccessViolation with arrays

Tags: c#, unsafe, .net-4.8

This question refers to the following issue at github: https://github.com/Efferent-Health/fo-dicom.Codecs/issues/23

We have the following source code (simplified):

```cs
    PinnedByteArray frameArray = new PinnedByteArray(frameData.Data);

    byte[] jpegData = new byte[frameData.Size];
    PinnedByteArray jpegArray = new PinnedByteArray(jpegData);
    
    uint jpegDataSize = 0;
    char[] errorMessage = new char[256];

    unsafe 
    {  
        CharlsApiResultType err = JpegLSEncode_Windows64((void*)jpegArray.Pointer, checked((uint)jpegArray.Count), &jpegDataSize, (void*)frameArray.Pointer, checked((uint)frameArray.Count),ref jls , errorMessage);

        Array.Resize(ref jpegData,(int)jpegDataSize); // <-- Crashes here with .NET 4.8

        IByteBuffer buffer = new MemoryByteBuffer(jpegData);

        newPixelData.AddFrame(buffer);
    }
```

As reported by a user, this code crashes in Array.Resize() when running on .NET Framework 4.8. We haven't heard about it when running on .NET Core.

The question is: Is there a safer way to handle the managed/unmanaged array to prevent Array.Resize() to crash?

Comment: are you *sure* that is actually the offending line? The debugger may in some cases show errors on the next line, and I would think it far more likely that `JpegLSEncode_Windows64` fails on an accessviolation than `Array.Resize`

Comment: This code is suspect to begin with -- in particular, `Array.Resize` may not do what you think it does. It does not resize an array in-place, as .NET arrays have a fixed size on creation. It creates a brand new array, copies data and reassigns the variable. Which is fine in managed code, except of course when the original value is being held by `PinnedByteArray` -- be aware that your *new* array is *not* pinned, and the old one (presumably) remains pinned despite this being unnecessary. If you're going to use `unsafe` and explicit pointers, I'd also be explicit with `fixed`.

Comment: HI @JeroenMostert can you post how we should use fixed in this case?

Comment: Basically, `fixed (byte* pJpegData = &jpegData) { /* use instead of jpegArray.Pointer */ } Array.Resize(...); fixed (byte* pJpegData = &jpegData) { ... }`. For a full answer I'd have to dive into what `JpegLSEncode_Windows64` actually does and what the broader context of this code is. It's likely all this `PinnedByteArray` hoopla is unnecessary and the P/Invoke signature of the function can be changed to just take `byte[]` without even needing `fixed` to (explicitly) pin the array.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to add

```
GC.KeepAlive(frameArray );
GC.KeepAlive(jpegData);
```

in the end of your method.

I would assume `PinnedByteArray` owns the native memory that is used, and that this it has a finalizer that free the memory after the object is collected. The last time these objects are used are *before* the call to `JpegLSEncode_Windows64`, so they are eligible for collection during the call. So the finalizer might free the memory while it is still being used. Gc.KeepAlive exist to handle this specific problem.

I would suspect that the the debugger shows the error on the wrong line, and that `Array.Resize` is innocent. I do not think there is any case where it can crash with a AccessViolationException, the only exception it should throw are `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Also, if you are on .Net core and are compressing/decompressing jpeg LS streams, I would suggest the CharLS library, it supports `Span<byte>`, removing the need for unsafe code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To clarify, we are not using any 3rd party library as we are an alternative library.
Regarding your suggestion of using KeepAlive, why should go at the end of the method? Should be invoked before JpegLSEncode?

Comment: It need to be run *after* JpegLSEncode. Since it will extend the lifetime of the object until after you are sure any unmanaged resources the object owns are no longer in use.